# Xampp apache server is not fetching glsl files?

Tags: javascript, php, apache, xampp

Basically I have a problem in my xampp apache server where's its not loading the glsl files as you can see here:

[image: image of my explorer in vscode]

As you can see, those files are all next to each other, however when I run it in the localhost, it basically gives these errors:

> GET http://localhost/shader.vs.glsl 404 (Not Found)
> GET http://localhost/shader.fs.glsl 404 (Not Found)
> graphics.js:58 ERROR: compiling vertex shader! ERROR: 0:1: '<' : syntax error`

which can be traced back due to a problem when the server runs, it does not fetch those glsl files, as you can see here

[image: image of my network panel in the developers tool]

It gave the status of these files as **error 404** basically, I really tried a lot to solve this problem, I used for example asking chatgpt, searching on google, talking with this issue on discord, and investigating the problem as well as trying different ways/changing in scripts, but it did not give any results.

Surprisingly it worked outside the Apache server....

Basically the program I'm doing is rendering a 3d crate, however im working on importing a 3d mesh in json, all using webgl, and an external library too, however I'm trying to get these glsl files on the server but it really gives **error 404** for some reason.

Any thoughts?

I need people to give possible solutions to that problem, as I failed miserably ....

Comment: Check the contents of XAMPP's document root.

Comment: what is that?, i mean give more detailed answer than just this

Comment: `utils.js` tries to load from a URL, but this URL doesn't resolve. Does the file reside within the webservers document root? Because it's loaded from there. Your project root directory is not neccessarily the webservers root...

Comment: i've putten the folder of new project on xampp/htdocs and which all files exist on that folder, and i think there's nothing with the url since there's no typo in the name, plus the files are literally next to eachother